# Summing rows in pandas dataframe which have a common value in one of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a pandas dataframe of numeric data, e.g.

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | b1 | 1 |
| 2 | a2 | b2 | 2 |
| 3 | a3 | b3 | 1 |
| 4 | a4 | b4 | 2 |

where a_n and b_n are just any numeric values.

Notice in column C there are 2 entries of 1 and 2 entries of 2. How do I deal with these duplicates such that I sum rows that have duplicate entries in C? i.e. the result is:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1+a3 | b1+b3 | 1 |
| 2 | a2+a4 | b2+b4 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

Simply [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) C and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df.groupby('C', as_index=False).sum()
```

To keep the original order of the columns:

```
df.groupby('C', as_index=False).sum()[df.columns]
```

Comment: dupe, unfortunately

Comment: I tried to bring some added value, but I guess OP could have searched better before asking

Comment: how do I also retain the original index? This answer works, except for keeping the original index. For example, in my question the index starts at 1 instead of 0. After doing groupby and sum, the index starts at 0.

Comment: nevermind it doesn't make sense to retain the original index, ignore that! thanks for the answer.

Comment: In python indexes and most counters start from 0, Assuming you save the output of the groupby+sum in `df_out` you could do `df_out.index += 1`